# Returning elements pushed to Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a question regarding arrays. I apologise if it has been asked before but I did a thorough search and couldn't find anything.

So I'm trying to write a simple bit of code. The idea is that the page loads, a prompt box comes up asking for a name, and that continues until no name is entered.

The problem is, when I try to call the array at the end, it only returns 'true', instead of the actual name entered.

I'm pretty new to arrays, but I have tried a bunch of stuff, and I can't seem to get the actual name values returned. Could anyone help with this?

```
    var enterNames = new Array();
    var i;

    while(i = prompt("Please enter a name", "") != "")
    {
        enterNames.push(i);
    }
    document.write(enterNames);
```

Thanks in advance for any light that could be shed on this.

Cheers,
Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence): in your `while` condition the `!=` is evaluated *first*, producing a boolean then the `=` assignment happens to assign that boolean value to `i`.

You can fix that using parentheses to group things as desired:

```
while((i = prompt("Please enter a name", "")) != "")
```

In context:

```js
var enterNames = [];
var i;

while((i = prompt("Please enter a name", "")) != "") {
    enterNames.push(i);
}
document.write(enterNames);
```

(Note that doing assignments within a loop condition is frowned upon by a lot of people, but obviously it does work. Also, note that generally `[]` is preferable to `new Array()` to create an empty array, but either works. And `document.write()` is almost always a bad plan.)

Comment: nnnnnn, thanks for your help, and for understanding why my code wasn't working. I know where I went wrong now :) Operator precedence is something I completely forgot about.
Thanks also for expanding on your answer. Some of the solutions I looked into indicated that [ ] was preferable, I'll start using that now. 
Also getting away from using document.write. Just used it for the purposes of this code. 
Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var enterNames = []; //instead of new Array();
function _prompt(){
  var i = prompt("Please enter a name", "");
  if(i==""){
    _prompt();
    return;
  }
  enterNames.push(i);
}
_prompt();
console.log(enterNames);
```

Comment: I like this Avril! Nice solution and makes sense to me. Thanks for your help!